# How to determine the number of iterations for Latent Dirichlet Allocation

Tags: topic-models, hyperparameter

I am performing Latent Dirichlet Allocation for 240 test documents (trained model with 3361 documents). I am using 150 iterations and 120 burn in iterations. Is there a specific way to determine iterations for the LDA process? I am computing for topics 1000, 1500,... 4500 (every 500th topic).

Answer (score 5):

A common way to determine the number of iterations is to compute perplexity as defined in D. Blei's [original LDA paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf). Perplexity describes how well the model fits the data by computing word likelihoods averaged over the test documents. When the difference in perplexity is smaller than a threshold, we can declare convergence and stop iterating.

For more advanced methods of evaluating LDA performance and some code, you can refer to the paper by [Wallach et al](http://mimno.infosci.cornell.edu/papers/wallach09evaluation.pdf).

There are many methods for estimating topics in LDA: variational, Gibbs sampling, EM. Since you mentioned burn-in, you are probably using the collapsed Gibbs sampler for inferring the topic distributions. In that case, you can use empirical MCMC convergence diagnostics such as Estimated Potential Scale Reduction.